# What happens to BroadcastReceiver when application is updated?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am setting an alarm (launched every 10 minutes) using `AlarmManager` together with `BroadcastReceiver` in my application.

What exactly happens when the application is updated (either by updating through Google Play or by installing application with higher version code directly through ADB), will the receiver still work? Can I trigger some actions related to `BroadcastReceiver` when the application is updated?

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you mean by "application is updated"? New version of application is installed on phone or something else? If you implemented BroadcastReceiver correctly in previous version and in new version it will of course still work. BroadcastReceiver receives an event, not sends one, what do you want to catch?

Comment: yes it will for sure, there should not be any effect on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to create alarms.
What makes you use BroadcastReceiver to create an alarm?

Is it that you have 2 applications and you are using BroadcastReceiver from app1 to launch the alarm[manager] from app2 ?

Otherwise, I believe your approach is wrong and BroadcastReceiver is renundant.

**UPDATE**

On the basis of your updated question, the crux of the question seems to be :

Will the BroadcastReceiver work if the applivcation is updated?

As long as you have the correct BroadcastReciever code in the updated verion of your app, it will.

---

Can I trigger some actions related to BroadcastReceiver when the application is updated?

You want to change your BroadcastReceiver/ remove your BroadCastreceiver --  you can.

Want some specific code to trigger on application being updated: use  ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED as ben75 suggested

Answer (score 2):

You can register a receiver for the action [ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REPLACED) to be notified when your app is updated.

But, in your particular use case : you probably setup the alarm when your app starts. After an application update: your app starts again and so the alarm will be setup correctly.